# htaccess rewrite rule for a pretty URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I need to turn a query string like this:

http://localhost/view.php?id=12345

Into this:

http://localhost/12345

But, I also plan on having a string on the end of the URL for search engines to benifit from, like so:

http://localhost/12345/NameOfTheSkin

Kind of like how Wowhead do their URL's:

```
http://www.wowhead.com/item=49623/shadowmourne
```

Notice how you can change the string "shadowmourne" into anything and it'll still point to the item id `49623`.

Basically, I need the string on the end to be ignored.

Any help is appreciated, cheers. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)/?.*$ /view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite `http://host/1234/some-text` and `http://host/1234` into `http://host/view.php?id=1234`.

Detailed explanation:

```
^   -- matches at the start of the string
(   -- start match group
\d+ -- match one or more digits
)   -- end match group
/?  -- match 0 or 1 slash
.*  -- match any character 0 or more times
$   -- matches at the end of the string
```

Visit [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for complete guide of regexp.

Comment: Why does that work? Could you include more details/explanation?

Comment: @Joe The first part of the rewrite rule `^/(\d+)/?.*$` is a regular expression that extracts digits `(\d+)` within the query string pattern `/xxx/?.*`. Where the `/?` tries to match a slash and `.*` matches everting to the end of the line `$`. This is then inserted to the request for view.php as `$1`  meaning the part matched by the first parenthesis (the digits).